Can't access spotify genres with Spotipy's recommendation_genre_seeds() function
I'm currently writing an application that takes in a user prompt and their listening data and creates a playlist for them. I also analyse the prompt with a bart model to identify which genres of music are most suitable.
In trying to get the list of genres that spotify uses with the Spotipy library's recommendation_genre_seeds() function, I've recently (over the past week) run into an exception that I did not previously get. The last time I wrote code for this application was around 3 - 4 weeks ago, when it ran smoothly.
I did some debugging in jupyter notebook. Given that I've initialised my spotipy model:
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, 
                                               client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, 
                                               redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, 
                                               scope="playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-read user-follow-read"))

Here is the snippet of code that throws the exception.
sp.recommendation_genre_seeds()
The exception is as follows.
HTTP Error for GET to https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations/available-genre-seeds with Params: {} returned 404 due to None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    274 
--> 275             response.raise_for_status()
    276             results = response.json()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
   1020         if http_error_msg:
-> 1021             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
   1022 

HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations/available-genre-seeds

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SpotifyException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19528\936109238.py in <module>
----> 1 sp.recommendation_genre_seeds()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in recommendation_genre_seeds(self)
   1731         """ Get a list of genres available for the recommendations function.
   1732         """
-> 1733         return self._get("recommendations/available-genre-seeds")
   1734 
   1735     def audio_analysis(self, track_id):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _get(self, url, args, payload, **kwargs)
    325             kwargs.update(args)
    326 
--> 327         return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
    328 
    329     def _post(self, url, args=None, payload=None, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py in _internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    295             )
    296 
--> 297             raise SpotifyException(
    298                 response.status_code,
    299                 -1,

SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations/available-genre-seeds:
 None, reason: None

Is there an issue with the spotify api that has caused Spotipy to crash like this? I've tried to look it up, I got some inkling of this issue but I just wanted to confirm that and also see if there's any workaround for this error.
Please let me know if there is any issue in my question as it is my first time posting on StackOverflow, thank you!

The underlying endpoint (/recommendations/available-genre-seeds) is not currently marked as deprecated in the documentation, but it is returning a 404 to the request sample as well. There's a good chance the endpoint stopped being supported on November 27, 2024 when the /recommendations endpoint was deprecated.

The documentation has now been updated, and the /recommendations/available-genre-seeds endpoint is also marked as deprecated.
You'll be getting an error as the recommendation_genre_seeds() function uses this endpoint to fetch the data.

understood, thank you!
